# Hide file previews in Dock folders?

Tags: finder, preview, dock, icon

When putting a folder in the Dock, clicking the folder shows the folder icons with previews of the content inside.

[image: file icon preview]

Is there any way to hide them and just show the regular file type icon? I tried pressing Command-J with the Finder folder open and unchecking "show icon preview", but that seems to not affect the dock folder.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at: [**Organize files in stacks on Mac - Apple Support**](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/organize-your-desktop-with-stacks-mh35846/mac)

From the **Use stacks in the Dock** section:

> - Change how folders look: Control-click the folder, then choose how the items in it are sorted, whether to show it in the Dock as a folder or a stack, and how to view its content (such as in a grid or fan).

A screen shot of my **stacks** on the **Dock**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you have a folder on the dock, you can right click it and click "Folder" under "Display As".